# Can't clear line in Python with \r

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar, flush

So I'm trying to make kind of a progress bar in Python, and in a for-loop I wrote this:

```
print(i, end='\r', flush=True)
sleep(0.1)
```

so it's supposed to write `0` then `1`, etc. But instead I get something like:

```
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I am using Spyder.

Here is the entire loop:

```
for i in range(it):
    _sum += z**i * f(i)
    print(i, end='\r', flush=True)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: please add your code including loop and what is that at the bottom? a list?

Comment: Where is the output going?  To a terminal screen?  Are you using a IDE?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as intended, it is hard to tell what the problem with your code was, since you only posted fractional code

If you are using a for loop with a list, then it must be formatted properly. use a list if you plan to use out of order numbers.

```
import time
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

for number in numbers:
    print(number, end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

If you want a sequential enumeration, then you can use a canonical expression:

```
for number in range(20):
    print(number, end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Or if you want to use a while loop

```
import time
n = 0
while n <= 15:
    n += 1
    print(n, end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

All three loops work as intended and in almost the same way

Comment: The canonical way of doing it is `for i in range(n):`, `i` is the number and `n` is the number of iterations.

Comment: Right, in my example the numbers are sequential in the list, so canonical expression would works, but if you notice his example is a long random list thus your approach would not work. But sure let's add it

Comment: OP's list does not seem random at all to me, it's `0` then `1` then `2` all the way up to `37` then `38` then `39`.

Comment: You are right. Well, if he want to use an out of order list, then he has an example to choose from. cheers

Comment: i can confirm what @Tomothy32 said. It's literally printing all the numbers without clearing the previous ones.

Comment: Since you are posting on my answer, did you try any of the examples I posted? they all work form me